# Send vertice shader changes to surface shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm trying to do a shader to curve the world like [Subway Surfer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Muh7QFisCfE&ab_channel=Throneful) does.

I have found a [GitHub repo](https://gist.github.com/grimmdev/9e63af5ab00c91d7ad09) where someone pushes an approximation for it that works cool.

This is the code:

```
 Shader "Custom/Curved" {
 Properties {
     _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
     _QOffset ("Offset", Vector) = (0,0,0,0)
     _Dist ("Distance", Float) = 100.0
 }
 SubShader {
     Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
     Pass
     {
         CGPROGRAM
         #pragma vertex vert
         #pragma fragment frag
         #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                     sampler2D _MainTex;
         float4 _QOffset;
         float _Dist;

         struct v2f {
             float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
             float4 uv : TEXCOORD0;
         };

         v2f vert (appdata_base v)
         {
             v2f o;
             float4 vPos = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_MV, v.vertex);
             float zOff = vPos.z/_Dist;
             vPos += _QOffset*zOff*zOff;
             o.pos = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_P, vPos);
             o.uv = v.texcoord;
             return o;
         }

         half4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR
         {
             half4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv.xy);
             return col;
         }
         ENDCG
     }
 }
 FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

The point is that now I want to send that new vertex positions to the surface shader to be able to have illumination an others.

I have read that I have to delete the fragment shader but I still having the problem that I can not send the new information to the surface shader.

This is my code:

```
Shader "Custom/Curve" {
 Properties{
     _Color("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
     _MainTex("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
     _Glossiness("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
     _Metallic("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0


     _QOffset("Offset", Vector) = (0,0,0,0)
     _Dist("Distance", Float) = 100.0
 }
     SubShader{
     Tags{ "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
     LOD 200

     CGPROGRAM

 #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows vertex:vert addshadow

 #pragma target 3.0

 sampler2D _MainTex;

 struct Input {
     float2 uv_MainTex;
 };

 half _Glossiness;
 half _Metallic;
 fixed4 _Color;

 float4 _QOffset;
 float _Dist;

 void vert(inout appdata_full v)
 {
     v.position.x += 10;
 }

 void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
     // Albedo comes from a texture tinted by color
     fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
     o.Albedo = c.rgb;
     // Metallic and smoothness come from slider variables
     o.Metallic = _Metallic;
     o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
     o.Alpha = c.a;
 }
 ENDCG
 }
     FallBack "Diffuse"
 }
```

As you can see now in the vertex shader I'm just trying to add some units to the X position of the vertex because I think that if I achieve that apply the "curved change" would be trivial but If you think It is not going to be that easy I would appreciate if you warn me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edited:

Here's an example for unity 2018.1
https://gist.github.com/bricevdm/caaace3cce9a87e081602ffd08dee1ad

```c
float4 worldPosition = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex); 
// get world space position of vertex
half2 wpToCam = _WorldSpaceCameraPos.xz - worldPosition.xz; 
// get vector to camera and dismiss vertical component
half distance = dot(wpToCam, wpToCam); 
// distance squared from vertex to the camera, this power gives the curvature
worldPosition.y -= distance * _Curvature; 
// offset vertical position by factor and square of distance.
// the default 0.01 would lower the position by 1cm at 1m distance, 1m at 10m and 100m at 100m
v.vertex = mul(unity_WorldToObject, worldPosition); 
// reproject position into object space
```

[image: screen capture from unity editor]

You are mixing up regular CG shaders and Surface shaders. Your sample from github is the former. `v.vertex` in Surface shaders is expected to be in **object space**, unlike `float4 pos : SV_POSITION` in the CG shader, which is expected to be in its final - **clip/screen space** - position.

The solution is to inverse the transformation back to object space. In your case you'd need to expose the inverse projection matrix from the camera.

replace `v.vertex = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_P, vPos);`
with this matrix: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-cameraToWorldMatrix.html. Since you transformed your vertex from object to camera space with UNITY_MATRIX_MV you need to reverse to world first, then to object space using unity_WorldToObject (or better combine both on the cpu).

**BUT** it is actually much easier to compute the curvature in **world space** with the matrices already provided:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-UnityShaderVariables.html

> unity_ObjectToWorld  Current model matrix.
>
> unity_WorldToObject   Inverse of current world matrix.

Comment: Sorry, but are you talking about  about the approach give to me in the other comment when you comment the `v.vertex = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_P, vPos);` part? 


I think I get the idea but I'm not sure about the implementation. Should I do the change to the "object space" in the vertex shader, do my curvature changes and move them back to the screen space ?

Comment: I've made a commented version here: https://gist.github.com/bricevdm/caaace3cce9a87e081602ffd08dee1ad

Answer (score 0):

It's because there isn't value as position in `appdata_full` struct:

```
struct appdata_full {
    float4 vertex : POSITION;
    float4 tangent : TANGENT;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
    float4 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 texcoord1 : TEXCOORD1;
    fixed4 color : COLOR;
#if defined(SHADER_API_XBOX360)
    half4 texcoord2 : TEXCOORD2;
    half4 texcoord3 : TEXCOORD3;
    half4 texcoord4 : TEXCOORD4;
    half4 texcoord5 : TEXCOORD5;
#endif
};
```

Instead of `v.position` use `v.vertex` like this:

```
void vert (inout appdata_full v, out Input o){
            UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(Input,o);
            v.vertex += 10;
}
```

And here Is surface version of your curve shader:

```
Shader "Custom/Curve" {
 Properties{
     _Color("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
     _MainTex("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
     _Glossiness("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
     _Metallic("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0


     _QOffset("Offset", Vector) = (0,0,0,0)
     _Dist("Distance", Float) = 100.0
 }
     SubShader{
     Tags{ "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
     LOD 200

     CGPROGRAM

 #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows vertex:vert addshadow

 #pragma target 3.0

 sampler2D _MainTex;

 struct Input {
     float2 uv_MainTex;
 };

 half _Glossiness;
 half _Metallic;
 fixed4 _Color;

 float4 _QOffset;
 float _Dist;

void vert (inout appdata_full v, out Input o){
            UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(Input,o);
            float4 vPos = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_MV, v.vertex);
            float zOff = vPos.z/_Dist;
            vPos += _QOffset*zOff*zOff;
            v.vertex = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_P, vPos);
            v.texcoord = v.texcoord;
}

 void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
     // Albedo comes from a texture tinted by color
     fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
     o.Albedo = c.rgb;
     // Metallic and smoothness come from slider variables
     o.Metallic = _Metallic;
     o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
     o.Alpha = c.a;
 }
 ENDCG
 }
     FallBack "Diffuse"
 }
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply:

I have did what you sugested me but the result is not the expected:
https://imgur.com/RixvcCI

I don't know what's happening exactly because also, when I only code in the vertex shader the "Position.x +=10" the displacement is not the correct:
https://imgur.com/gGuthTN

Comment: @CarlosHdezBarbera can you send result problem?

Comment: @CarlosHdezBarbera I mentioned use `v.vertex.x += 10;` . can you describe what happened in two images? what do you expect exactly?

Comment: Of course, I have uploaded two videos example to show what's happening. I can understand that maybe the curve shader is wrong(i don't know how because in the git repo it works how is expected) but the x displacement is not working as I expect and I can't understand it.

Example 1: https://youtu.be/kFpyySpfVik
Example 2: https://youtu.be/nhLdvQEQKIw

Comment: @CarlosHdezBarbera I had experience that sometimes vertex shader don't work correctly and you need to add `Tags{ "DisableBatching" = "true"}` like [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/143205/why-does-duplicating-my-object-cause-its-vertex-animation-shader-to-distort-it)

Comment: as I understand they don't move at same time.you said git repo it works expected so what is difference between surface shader and vertex shader! sorry but I haven't idea!